# Is it possible to store a function call in a dynamic variable?

Tags: javascript

Also with a dynamic variable name. I tried doing it so:

```
let positionAx = [450, 420, 425, 425, 430, 444, 449, 453, 449, 471, 475]; // x + z Coordinates for the following units in order: 
let positionAz = [541, 532, 532, 558, 558, 566, 566, 566, 562, 542, 546]; // CC, melee x2, ranged x2, female x4, cavalry x1, special x1

let dynamicShiftx = ["position" + poppedPosition + "x" + ".shift();"]; 
let dynamicShiftz = ["position" + poppedPosition + "z" + ".shift();"]; 
            
let shiftPositionX = dynamicShiftx;
let shiftPositionZ = dynamicShiftz;
```

both `dynamicShiftx` and `dynamicShiftz` yield what i need which is `positionAx.shift();` and `positionAz.shift();` but it doesnt actually shift that value. What am i doing wrong? js newbie btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object to group the arrays, then you can generate a string key that lets you access the array you want using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) like so:

```
let positions = {
  Ax: [450, 420, 425, 425, 430, 444, 449, 453, 449, 471, 475],
  Az: [541, 532, 532, 558, 558, 566, 566, 566, 562, 542, 546],
  Bx: ...
  ...
};

let shiftPositionX = positions[poppedPosition + "x"].shift(); 
let shiftPositionZ = positions[poppedPosition + "z"].shift();
```